# Backups to google drive failing with RedirectMissingLocation error

Tags: backup, deja-dup, google-drive

Trying to set up an initial backup in Ubuntu 18.04 on google drive with a deja-dup installed as follows due to a known [authentication error](https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1747646):

> snap install deja-dup --classic --beta

The backup fails at the very end with the following error:

[image: screenshot error]

> Backup Failed
>
> Giving up after 5 attempts. RedirectMissingLocation: Redirected but the response is missing a Location:header

It sounds like the error reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59815620/gcloud-upload-httplib2-redirectmissinglocation-redirected-but-the-response-is-m), caused by a broken httplib2 version 0.15.0, however my httplib2 version is 0.9.2 according to apt and pip3.

edit: updated httplib2 to 0.17.0 through pip3, but to no avail. Backup still fails at the very end after running for several hours and uploading 80GB onto google drive.

edit2: installed google-auth-httplib2 through pip3 and restarted laptop, but to no avail either.

edit3: installed google-auth-httplib2 through pip and restarted laptop, but again to no avail. Is there a way to check which httlplib2 Backup is using and to get some debug output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a bug with httplib2, the developers released a hotfix for it. See [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/World/deja-dup/-/issues/74)

As you have the snap version, it doesn't make a difference what dependencies you have installed, all dependencies are resolved in the Snap.

As such the accepted solution is wrong, their instructions will only affect users who do have deja-dup installed from the apt repository.

Comment: I see, that explains why it miraculously started working a week ago. And here I thought it was due to the packages I installed a month ago.

Answer (score 2):

There are broken dependencies in duplicity

First install librsync-dev

```
apt install  librsync-dev
```

and than in order:

```
pip3 install httplib2
pip3 install google-auth-httplib2
pip3 install duplicity
pip3 install apiclient
pip3 install PyDrive
```

Now I have perfectly running duplicity backup with GD

```
google-auth-httplib2 (0.0.3)              - Google Authentication Library: httplib2 transport
  INSTALLED: 0.0.3 (latest)
httplib2 (0.17.0)                         - A comprehensive HTTP client library.
  INSTALLED: 0.15.0
```

and duplicity:

```
duplicity 0.8.11
```

Cheers,

Dimitar

Comment: Thanks for the hint with google-auth-httplib2, I think that definitely goes to the right direction. I installed the packages you listed (both via pip and pip3) and restarted my laptop, but still get the same error at the end of the backup. Is there a way to get some info on Ubuntu backup (as in: which httlplib2 version it is using) and perhaps some debug info?

Comment: Have you tried the non-snap version of deja-dup?

Comment: I used only pip3 only, and  duplicity (actually it makes the backup) I've installed with pip3 as well. **apt install  librsync-dev** was crucial as well.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I started with the default version of deja-dup on Ubuntu, but I encountered the following authentication bug, which I resolved by using the snap version: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/1747646